# Запуск ассоциированных файлов

Tags: java, winapi

в моей программе есть функция сохранения проекта, одновременно можно работать над несколькими проектами. Ассоциацию созданных файлов реализовал через реестр:

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ProgramProject\shell\open\command]
@="\"D:\\t\\Program\\Program.exe\" \"%1\""`,

при двойном клике на файл проекта в проводнике, запускается новый экземпляр программы.

Вопрос: как сделать так чтобы при двойном клике на файл проекта, открывался новый проект в уже существующем экземпляре программы.

Кусок кода в программе отвечающий за запуск проекта через клик по файлу:

```
if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
for (String arg : args) {
    File file = new File(arg);
    FileHandle fileHandle = new FileHandle(file);
    if (fileHandle.exists() && fileHandle.extension().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).equals(save_file_extension)) {
        loadProject(fileHandle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Со стороны WinAPI (у вопроса тег WinAPI) штатных способов такой реализации нет.

Двойной клик всегда запустить новый экземпляр программы, поэтому чтобы файл открылся в существующем экземпляре экземпляры должны общаться с друг другом. Запуск экземпляра, проверка что запущен другой экземпляр, передача ему имени проекта.

Если это реализовывать средствами WinAPI, то есть несколько способов.

При запуске приложения создается мьютекс `OpenMutex`, регистрируется глобальное сообщение `RegisterWindowMessage`, отвечая на которое предыдущий экземпляр передает идентификатор своего окна, через сообщение `WM_COPY` передается строка предыдущему экземпляру. Для простоты в `OpenMutex` и `RegisterWindowMessage` я использовал один строкой идентификатор.

Вроде есть способ еще через *memory-mapped file*.

Есть ли какие-то обертки на *java* этих способов не знаю.